# Jasmine testing in Rails Engine

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jasmine

I am creating a gem (created with `rails plugin new --full`) and I want to test my JavaScript with Jasmine.

I have the `spec/javascripts` stuff set up, but it continues to fail to pull in the the files in `app/assets` (not `spec/dummy/app/assets`).

I've tried both the approaches in these posts (basically attempting to force compile the assets):

- [Pivotal Labs: Writing and running Jasmine specs with Rails 3.1 and Coffeescript](http://pivotallabs.com/users/jdean/blog/articles/1778-writing-and-running-jasmine-specs-with-rails-3-1-and-coffeescript)
- [Testing a Rails 3.1 Engine's Javascript with Jasmine](http://sleeplessgeek.blogspot.com/2011/08/testing-rails-31-engines-javascript.html)

In both cases, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'tmp:cache:clear'
```

In the case of the pivotal labs solution, I also get:

```
undefined method `static_root=' for #<Sprockets::Environment:0x007febe4348ac8>
```

My code is here: https://github.com/rmw/pixelator/tree/master/spec/javascripts

How can I get the asset pipeline to compile?

Thanks!

Comment: I use evergreen to get around all that mess. Also you should use bundler to create new gems.

Comment: Are you OK with using Guard to dynamically compile your assets? Might be a way to skirt the issue.

Comment: Also, can you link to a public repository with example code?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the

> guard-jasmine

gem?